# PHPExcel Invalid File Created

Tags: php, phpexcel, file-format

I have a little PHPExcel script which outputs a Excel File the problem is, when I open it from server I can open it with no problem. But when I download it via header in Browser it doesn't works.

I searched the problem in internet but I didn't find anything which helped me, I tried with ob_clean();, I checked if BOM is the problem, nothing worked.

So I hope some of you has the ONE idea wich will let my script work.

```
$this->objPHPExcel = $this->objReader->load($this->newFilePath);
    $objWorksheet = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    //Adding IO General Overhead
    foreach($this->sums as $sumkey => $sumval){
        foreach($sumval as $keys => $vals){
            foreach($vals as $key => $val){
                $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($key, $offset[$sumkey][$keys], $val);
            }
        }
        $objWriter->save($this->newFilePath);
    }

    ob_clean();

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');


    // It will be called file.xls
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->newFilePath.'"');

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

Comment: As always.... open file in a text editor and check for any leading/trailing whitespace (including BOM marker), or any obvious plaintext error messages in the stream of data.... I have to repeat this so often, I really should set up a macro for it

Comment: But looking at your code, where are you sending the file to the browser? You either need to save to php://output __after__ sending the headers; or readfile($this->newFilePath) after sending the headers

Answer (score 0):

Look at 01simple-download-xlsx.php in /Tests or /Examples for a sample of code that does what you want:

```
$this->objPHPExcel = $this->objReader->load($this->newFilePath);
    $objWorksheet = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    //Adding IO General Overhead
    foreach($this->sums as $sumkey => $sumval){
        foreach($sumval as $keys => $vals){
            foreach($vals as $key => $val){
                $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($key, $offset[$sumkey][$keys], $val);
            }
        }
    }


    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');


    // It will be called file.xls
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->newFilePath.'"');

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

        $objWriter->save('php://output');
```